# MPI_BCast doesn't work with MPI_Comm_Split

Tags: c, mpi

i'm a rookie in mpi programming, so i tried to implement a little program that split all process into a group with a new comunicator.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    MPI_Comm central_server_comm, intermediary_server_comm, lolcal_devices_comm;
    int new_color;

    if (rank == 0) {
        // The process with rank 0 is the central server
        new_color = 0;
    } else if (rank == 1) {
        // The process with the rank 1 is the intermediary server
        new_color = 1;
    } else {
        // The other processes are local devices
        new_color = 2;
    }

    MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, new_color, rank, &central_server_comm);

   float message[4]; // Initializes an array of floating-point numbers

    if (new_color == 0) {
        
        // This is the central server
        printf("I am the central server. Rank %d of %d.\n", rank, size);
        // Initialize the array with the desired numbers
        message[0] = 1.0;
        message[1] = 2.0;
        message[2] = 3.0;
        message[3] = 4.0;
        MPI_Send(message, 4, MPI_FLOAT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // Broadcast to everyone
    } else if (new_color == 1) {
        // This is an intermediary server
        printf("I am the intermediary server. Rank %d of %d.\n", rank, size);
        MPI_Bcast(message, 4, MPI_FLOAT, 0, central_server_comm); // Ricevi il messaggio da server centrale
        printf("Message received from central server: %f %f %f %f\n", message[0], message[1], message[2], message[3]);
    } else {
        //This is a local device
        printf("I am a local device. Rank %d of %d.\n", rank, size);
        MPI_Bcast(message, 4, MPI_FLOAT, 0, central_server_comm); // Ricevi il messaggio da server intermedio
        printf("Message received from intermediary server: %f %f %f %f\n", message[0], message[1], message[2], message[3]);
    }

    MPI_Comm_free(&central_server_comm);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

[I let also a wrong output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7QB5.png)

I want that the process with rank = 0 send the data to the process with rank = 1, and this last process send in broadcast the data to all other process, but when i try to send an integer data everything works correcty, but when i try to send an other type of data (like float or char) it send null valure (0.0 for float and " " for char). I let the code down here. I hope that someone can help me please.I think that i wrong something with the function mpi_comm_split, but i don't know what.

Comment: I don't see the receive corresponding to the send for color zero.

Comment: `MPI_Bcast()` happens within the communicator. For example, if you consider rank `1` in `MPI_COMM_WORLD`, it is alone it its communicator and `message` is uninitialized.

Comment: @Gilles Sorry, but I did not understand. I solved the problem by working around it, but now I tried to implement another program and encountered the same problem. I want the process with global rank 0 to initialize the array, but when I do this in a condition for the process with rank 0 and try to broadcast the message, the receiver receives an uninitialized value. So, I understand that the array is only initialized in the memory location of process 0, but why if I try to send this value to other processes it's like it doesn't send it?

Comment: the sender and receivers must be in the same communicator for `MPI_Bcast()` to work as you expect.